# Android-Toast in place of no action

Tags: android, types, toast

Basically we can set  the EditBox to accept a particular datatype i.e .`android:InputType="number"`. Suppose, if we type in with alphabets, then the characters won't be added into the EditBox i.e. no action takes place. What I want is that a Toast must be displayed defining "Alphabets are not allowed". What kind of code can I try?

Answer (score 3):

set a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) in your `EditText`. When there is any change then the `onTextChange` method will be called. In there you can check the validity.

For Example

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // check vallidity if there is any alphabet show toast
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

You can use other two methods also. I think the name of the methods clearly tells their purpose

Comment: You beat me to the answer by 9 seconds! :(

Comment: @swayam oops .. the same answer .. ok +1 for you for right aswer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement your own **`TextWatcher`** like

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // check if the entered character is valid or not. If not valid, then show Toast
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // 
    }
});
```